# How do I trigger a Fever?

Tags: pokemon-rumble-world

I noticed that when I pick a stage with my balloon, sometimes I get Fever, which allows me to go to areas with more stars.

Is there a way to trigger a Fever, or is it random? If it isn't random, how do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Fever is a completely random event.

> The method of getting this is **completely random**, but there is a way to see if you're likely to get one. When you return from a previous stage, if there is a rainbow around your balloon in the cutscene, then you have a chance of getting Fever in your next stage, so be sure to make sure you know what stage you're selecting first.

Source: [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/rumbleworld/travel.shtml)

Comment: Also, you have an even more rare chance to get a super fever, which if on a certain balloon (Ruby,Sapphire ect) You have a chance for atleast 2 legendaries to appear.

Comment: @JDWhaler Super Fever can only happen when you have at least 2-3 rainbows on the background, I think.

Comment: Confirmed: It does happen with atleast one rainbow, I experienced it yesterday

Answer (score 0):

Fever is indeed random but the rainbows seem to be dependent on how high of a chain you make in the last stage you played, I've found that as long as I keep my chain over 50 at least once in the stage, I get 3 rainbows and a higher chance at super fever.

Answer (score 0):

I too agree it is completely random but combos up to 20-30 and you get a really high chance of getting fever. However, you need to be patient, so try until you get it.

Answer (score 0):

It is random, but if the island is on cool-down, just close the clam-shell, and the fever will still be there. I tried it, and I got a Kyogre.

Answer (score -1):

It is somewhat random. If you see tons of white lines swirling around the base of the area, and if you can see a rainbow in the background, it is likely to go into fever mode